# Are JavaScript Array elements nothing more than Array object properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, element

I have observed the following:

```
var o = {}; // empty JS object
var a = []; // empty JS array

o.myproperty = "I am property";
a.push("I am array element");

alert(o['myproperty']); // alerts "I am property"
alert(o.myproperty); // alerts "I am property"
alert(a[0]); // alerts "I am array element"
alert(a['0']); // alerts "I am array element"

/* Of course, accessing an array element using dot notation (e.g. a.0) would cause a
   SyntaxError: Unexpected number (in JavaScript variable names cannot begin with numbers.)
*/
```

Also:

```
'myproperty' in o // evaluates to true
0 in a // true
'0' in a // true

delete o.myproperty; // true, o is now empty
delete o['myproperty']; // true, o is now empty
delete a[0]; // true, a contains now 1 undefined element
delete a['0']; // true, a contains now 1 undefined element
```

It seems as if adding an element to an array actually creates a numbered property on the array object, that is afterwards used to access the element by reference. But some things do not work on these *array element properties* exactly as they do on normal object properties (an example is the above deletion). So...

**TL;DR**
... Are javascript array elements accessed by reference via unseen numbered array object properties?

**EDIT**
seems so: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the only thing an `Array` adds over an `Object` is the `.length` property, and a few array-specific methods like `.push`. That's really it, under the hood an `Array` is just an `Object`. What really makes it usable as an array is said `.length` parameter; it allows you to *iterate* the properties in an *ordered* manner with a `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop. The `.length` property is updated when you `.push()` new elements into the array or when doing some other array-specific manipulations. And that's really all you need to make an object work as an indexed, ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

To make an accessor value an **index** in the array it should:

- Be a non-negative integer (`0`, `1`, `100`, `200`);
- If converted to a number (from a `string`), it should be a non-negative integer ('0', '1.000')

For example:

```
a['100'] // as index a[100]
a['0']   // as index a[0]
a[1.00]  // as index a[1]
```

---

In all other cases the accessor is treated as a **property** of the array object:

```
a[-1]       // as a property a['-1']
a['myProp'] // as a property a['myProp']
```

---

What makes the array different from regular objects: when using indexes  the `length` property is auto-updated. The `length` should be always bigger by 1 than the highest index.

Comment: But what does "treated as an index" mean? What are the differences between an index property, and another property? probably what @deceze said in his answer

Comment: @Nonorios "treated as an index" means that setting a value will increase the `length` based on highest index. When setting regular properties, the `length` is not auto-updated.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are Objects, the simplest way to see it is `[] instanceof Object` which returns `true`.

And yes, Array elements are accessed by reference the same way Object properties are.

When you delete a property of an Object, you are actually setting this property to undefined, so it's the same for an object or an array.